# Bounded computation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc

Is there any way in Haskell (using GHC if it matters, for code that needs to run on Linux and Windows) to perform bounded computation? That is, "compute the result of this function if it is feasible to do so, but if the attempt has used more than X CPU cycles, Y stack space or Z heap space, and still not done, stop and return an indication that it was not possible to complete the computation"?

Comment: Are you building some model checking tool?

Comment: Among other things, yes.

Comment: This might be of interest too: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/speculation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
System.Timeout.timeout :: Int -> IO a -> IO (Maybe a)
```

http://lambda.haskell.org/hp-tmp/docs/2011.2.0.0/ghc-doc/libraries/base-4.3.1.0/System-Timeout.html#v:timeout

Comment: Thanks! That definitely looks like the answer for limited time. Looking through that section of the documentation, there doesn't seem to be any similar solution for memory?

Comment: Indeed.  I can't imagine any sensible semantics for memory, though -- besides the extreme difficulty of measuring memory consumption precisely, what if there's another thread that's not memory constrained?  What if you share some values with that other thread; who "pays for it"?  How do you resolve those issues quickly enough to get measurements without crippling the function that's being run?

Comment: Yeah, these are hard problems and honestly I wasn't optimistic about the probability of a general-purpose language providing an off-the-shelf solution, but I figured it was worth a try before resigning myself to hacking my own memory management etc. in C++ :-)

Comment: I suppose?  (I mean, I would try to find my way around the problem instead of through before resorting to such fearsome measures, but I don't know the context.)

Comment: Careful now: `Int` is particularly small when it comes to microseconds. See also the [unbounded-delays](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unbounded-delays) package.

Comment: @DanielWagner `Int` is more than adequate on 64-bit GHC.

Comment: @NathanHowell It sounds like he's doing some cross-architecture stuff (since he mentions at least two operating systems), so being careful of `Int` makes a lot of sense to me. For example, right now, there *are* no 64-bit GHC's for Windows.

Comment: @DanielWagner while it does still surprise me that 64-bit support isn't quite there yet on Windows, `Int` does work just fine for this on 64-bit builds.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a hackish solution you *could* try: spawn your computation with `forkIO`, and let the parent thread (or a monitoring thread which has access to the forked thread's `ThreadId`) periodically poll for any quantity you'd want, and throw an asynchronous exception to the computing thread as necessary (interestingly, that's exactly how `timeout` works.)

The next question would be whether there's a way to find out how big the heap currently is from within Haskell. Total memory consumption and cycles you can find out by spawning shell commands, or querying the OS in another way (I wouldn't know how to do that on Windows.)

It's not a perfect solution, but it's a simple one, which you could implement and test in a couple of minutes.

Comment: I was hunting for a memory-in-use method, but couldn't find one within Haskell.

Comment: Instead of monitoring the heap usage of the fork, you could as well just limit its heap with `RTS`opts, couldn't you?

Comment: `forkIO` is within the same Haskell program.  Unless you're actually spawning a new process, you're working within the shared heap.

Answer (score 6):

On a per-process level, you can use [GHC's RTS options](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/runtime-control.html) to control maximum stack and heap sizes.